# saving canvas without displaying contents

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I'm drawing lots to a canvas (canvas1) and want to know if it's feasible to draw to a 2nd canvas (canvas2) without drawing to the screen.

Then save the canvas2 to the file system even though it's not been displayed to the screen.

This is what I have for canvas2

```
 Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;  //Config.RGB_565;
 KeyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), conf); 
 canvas2 = new Canvas(KeyBitmap);

 .....
 canvas1 stuff
```

Then the onDraw method is using canvas1 and displays successfully to the screen

During ondraw I also draw to canvas2 like this

```
 canvas2.drawRect(key_offset_left + (key_col_count * bestsize),                 //left 
                                key_offset_top + (key_row_count*bestsize),                  //top
                                key_offset_left + (key_col_count * bestsize) + bestsize -1, //right
                                key_offset_top + (key_row_count * bestsize) + bestsize -1,  //bottom
                                paint3);
```

Later I want to be able to save the canvas2 bitmap (KeyBitmap) without displaying it to the screen, this is what I have

```
    String mfolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp";
    KeyBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(mfolder + "/chart2.jpg")));
```

A file is created which has a black background and no drawn rectangle content.
I checked that the drawRect is drawing successfully by temporarily changing canvas2 to canvas1

The reason why I want to draw to the second canvas is that I have run out of screen to display both on one canvas. I've implemented zoom and pan which works when I draw it all to one canvas but when I want to save to the file system it only captures what is viewable in the view and to make content readable some of the content needs to be off visible screen. That's why I'm trying to do it as two canvas and then save as separate files.

Any ideas why my canvas2 code does not output what is drawn to it?

Thanks

Comment: use (Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

Comment: Thanks, PNG output is still blank, 1.55KB. Am I right to expect output from canvas2 when it never appears on the screen?

Comment: what do you mean: output ?

Comment: I'm confused, setting canvas1.setBitmap(KeyBitmap) solved it, but to me that doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes it makes no sense, you did something wrong, post more code